# Simpler and more common way of asking "Where could he/she had gone?"

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I'm not a native English speaker, and I though asking "Where could he/she had gone?" was very common. But when I [searched](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Where%20could%20he%20had%20gone%20to%22#fp=ff11eed4a3239840&psj=1&q=%22where%20could%20he%20had%20gone%22) that phrase in Google I got only 6 results.

Is there a more simpler, more common way of asking that question?

Comment: Modal verbs (*can/could, may/might, must, shall/should, will/would*) always require that the next verb in the construction be cast in the infinitive (plain) form: in this case, *have* rather than *has* or *had*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got only 7 hits because you have the ungrammatical “could **had** gone” instead of the correct “could **have** gone”.  If you fix your *had* into a *have*, it will be fine.

Comment: I could had eaten a hamburger before I had eaten a box of chicken nuggets;)

Comment: @Noah, completely ungrammatical to me. “I could ***have had*** eaten a hamburger …” is fine, though, although much too convoluted for my taste. Why not just, “I could have eaten a hamburger before I ate a box of chicken nuggets”? I can't think of any situation where I would use the pluperfects here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I believe he’s referring to the [lolcats’ *I can has cheezburger?*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Can_Has_Cheezburger%3F) Internet meme .

Comment: @tchrist, perhaps … though somewhat too obscurely so for me, if so. In lolspeak, I would have expected, “I could/cud had eated a hamburgerz before I had eated a box of chiken nugits” or something like that. A missing auxiliary does not lolspeak make. :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I know it's completely ungrammatical;)

Answer (score 0):

There are 11,900,000 links  for this [where could he have gone](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22where%20could%20he%20have%20gone%22&oq=%22where%20could%20he%20have%20gone%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.874j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Is that the question you want to ask?

Answer (score 0):

I usually would say "Where'd [s]he go?"

The "could had gone" may indicate worrying if [s]he will ever return. If you want to convey your concern, then you should stick with "Where could [s]he had gone?"

Edit: I missed that "had gone" should have been "have gone". Thank you.

Comment: -1 "could *had* gone" and "Where could [s]he *had* gone?" are **not** English.